# Obtaining Consent with the User Messaging Platform (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, gdprconsentform, ump

I am trying to obtain consent with the User Messaging Platform (UMP). I have followed the official documentation, but I still have some questions.

- When I try to test the consent flow using the `setConsentDebugSettings()` method, it does not work. I had to go into the AdMob console under **Privacy & Messages** and change the geography target for my GDPR dialog from **Countries subject to GDPR (EEA and UK)** to **Everywhere**. Only then was the consent dialog able to display.
- After the consent dialog has been displayed to the user and they have either consented or rejected, I am not sure where to initialize the AdMob SDK and load the ads.
- Every time the app is launched, the consent process starts again and again. I am not sure if this is because I keep calling `consentInformation.reset()` in the code.
- Finally, I do not know what to do if `consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN` is true. Should I initialize the SDK and load ads, or not? What about if `onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError)` occurs?

I am all turned around. Please help me! Here is the code I have attempted so far:

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

```
ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .build();

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                                loadForm();
                                consentInformation.reset();
                            }
                            else
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.NOT_REQUIRED
                                    ||consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                InnitializeAdmobSdk();
                                Load_Admob_ads();
                                consentInformation.reset();
                            }
                            else
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UNKNOWN"+" "+consentInformation.getConsentStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                consentInformation.reset();
                            }

                        }else{
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.NOT_REQUIRED
                                    ||consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                InnitializeAdmobSdk();
                                Load_Admob_ads();
                                consentInformation.reset();
                            }
                            else
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus()== ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UNKNOWN"+" "+consentInformation.getConsentStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            consentInformation.reset();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }
                });
```

This is the loadform method

```
public void loadForm() {
        // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                                // App can start requesting ads.
                                            }

                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Admob have created a sample for you to refer to https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/kotlin/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerexample

Comment: but this is in kotlin, I use java

Comment: this would be the java version.   https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/java/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerexample

Comment: Can you tell me how you handled the situation? I don't quite understand, if the consent is refused, can I show ads or not?